# mysql | unable to find config file

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-notifier

I have start working on replication on mysql so what i did for that i made two port on my system (same IP address). now I am unable to find second config file. I am running mysql server 5.7.instance Information these are the two instance i created with different port nos.

[image: instance Information these are the two instance i created with different port nos]

Now I am not able to find the config file. any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: We don't do your work for you.

Comment: Give example values and expected output please e.g. Should 12.57 be rounded to 12, 12.5, 12.6 or 13? Should 12,34 be rounded to 12, 12.3 or 12.5.. etc

Comment: Please specify the amount data type , how you want it rounded (to whole number?) and example input and result.

Comment: Also, decide which database system you're actually using!

Comment: @CharlieFish if you don't know the answer then you don't need to comment,

Comment: @DeepakKavin we cant help you If you don´t provide a specific question, with a example and some input.

Comment: @DeepakKavin Who said I didn't know the answer?

Comment: @CaiusJard Thanks for reply, e.g i am having a value $999.75 then i want to make a round off $1000 hope you got my point.

Comment: You want 999.01 to round up to 1000?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Round(yourColumn, 0) AS RoundedColumn
FROM Table;
```

[Round(Value, decimal)](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_msaccess_round.asp) is the thing your searching for. If you want to update it you should have to write something like:

```
UPDATE table
SET yourColumn = Round(yourColumn, 0)
WHERE condition; //Only if you want to specify specific rows
```

Comment: If it works for you mark it as answered, Caius Jard also mentioned the ceiling function which could help you too

Comment: no actualy you put the query for update which i don't want i just want to see the data mean select command, so i can't mark as answer so i put only useful as i got the idea with round(PurchaseAmt, 0) function.

Comment: I wrote you the select function too and just mentioned the update cause you not specified what you want to achieve but whatever.

Comment: cool i just saw only the last query now its fine. i marked as answered

Answer (score 1):

Based on the limited example you posted in comments you either want to look up the ROUND function or the CEILING function. Ceiling always rounds up, round will round either down or up depending on which side of .5 the value is

Comment: yes you are also right i already got the idea from previous user comment but your comment also appreciated.

Comment: You could also mention FLOOR to complete the triumvirate.

Comment: @dav1dsm1th I could, but it didn't align with the specified example operation the OP wanted to perform